Using ScaLAPACK subroutine PDGEMR2D gives errors
I am working on a problem where I need the full spectrum of a Hamiltonian matrix. I order to have a better performance, I am using ScaLAPACK  routine PDSYEV to compute the eigenstates and eigenvalues of  very large matrices (N > 15000), and the results are very impresive. But, after computing the eigenstates, I need to calculate some other dynamical properties, thus I need  to have all the eigenstates  into a single  matrix in a single process. Using pdgemr2d works fine for N up to 20000, but for larger values I get  the error :  xxmr2d core aborted. My cluster has 128GB RAM , 32 CPU/64 threads.
This is how I  organized the code.
   .... 
   call MPI_INIT(info)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank, info)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nprocs, info)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nsize, info)
   nprow = 4
   npcol = 4
   block = 6
   call  blacs_get(-1,0,ictxt)
   call  blacs_gridinit(ictxt,"R",nprow, npcol)
   call  blacs_gridinfo(ictxt, nprow, npcol, myrow, mycol)
  ! print*, "myrank", myrank, myrow,mycol
   np = numroc(nst,block,myrow,0,nprow)
   nq = numroc(nst,block, mycol, 0,npcol)
   lld = max(1,np)
   call descinit(descAloc,nst,nst,block,block, 0,0, ictxt,np,info)
  ! print*, "INFO descinit A", info
  ! print*, "descAloc", descAloc
   call DESCINIT(descZ, nst, nst, block, block, 0, 0, ictxt,np, info)
   call DESCINIT(descZglobal, nst, nst, nst, nst, 0,0,ictxt,nst,info)
   call DESCINIT(descdumm, nst,nst,block,block,0,0,ictxt,np,info)
   !print*, "info descinit Z", info
   pi=acos(-1.d0) ! value of pi
   fi = 0.0/N_site
   phase =  dcmplx(cos(fi),sin(fi))
  
   !if  we  eigenvalues only 
   ! lworkk = 5*nst + max(3*block,block*(np+1))+1 
   !  if also eigenvectors 
    lworkk =  max( 1 + 6*nst + 2*np*nq, 3*nst + max( block*( np+1 ), 3*block)) + 2*nst
   allocate(Z(lld,lld), Aloc(lld,lld),workk(lworkk), wrk(np)) ! allocate memory to construct the full Hamiltonian matrix, j operator matrix for the calculated number of states in the Sz=0 sector 
      do local_i = 1 , np
        do local_j = 1 , nq
           ! Determine the global indicies (i,j) from the local indices   (local_i,local_j)
           i = indxl2g(local_i,block,myrow,0,nprow)
       j = indxl2g(local_j,block,mycol,0,npcol)
           ! Compute Hmatc(i,j) directly
           if (i == j) then 
           Aloc(local_i,local_j) = real(AD(i))
       else 
       Aloc(local_i, local_j) = 0.d0  ! Initialize to zero 
           do ih = row_ptr(i),row_ptr(i+1) - 1
          ij = col_ind(ih)
          isig = sign(1,col_ind_oper(ih))
              if (ij == j) then 
          if (isig == 1) then 
          Aloc(local_i,local_j) = Aloc(local_i,local_j) + 0.5*J_int
          else 
          Aloc(local_i,local_j) = Aloc(local_i,local_j) - 0.5*isig*J_int
              end if 
          end if 
           end do 
           end if 
        end do 
      end do 
   call pdsyev("v","u",nst,Aloc,1,1,descAloc,W,Z,1,1,descZ,workk,lworkk,info)
   if(myrank ==0) then 
   write(0,*) "info pdsyev", info 
   end if 
   if(myrank == 0) then
        write(0,*) "First and last eigenvalues :"
        write(0,"(6f5.2)") W(1),W(2),W(3),W(nst-2),W(nst-1),W(nst)
   write(0,*) "info pdsyev", info 
   end if     
   allocate(Zglobal(nst,nst)) ! global matrix to store all eigenvectors 
   call pdgemr2d(nst,nst, Z,1,1,descz, Zglobal, 1,1, descZglobal,ictxt)


   if(myrank == 0) then 
   deallocate(Zglobal)
   end if
    deallocate (Z)
    call blacs_gridexit(ictxt)
    call MPI_FINALIZE(info)

I compile the code as in following:
 mpiifx problem.f90 -qmkl=cluster
 mpirun -np 16 ./a.out

the error is : cannot allocate memory, aborted xxmr2d: out of memory

Is this a 64-bit compiler?  A 20k square array of doubles takes 3.2GB.  If you're making very many copies of that (intentionally or not), you're going to hit memory limits pretty quickly.

@VladimirFГероямслава thank you for your response.   I am sure they are not runtime errors. The problems  is related to MB Quantum Mechanics, ore axactly with spin systems.  It works perfectly for systems up to 17 sites, but increasing the system size, increses also the number of states exponentially. For L=18 sites, the memory crashes, even though  there are 128 GB of RAM. The results are correct for the systems I calculated.
mpiifx  problem.f90 -qmkl=cluster
mpirun -np 16 ./a.out
I get:
Intel oneMKL ScaLAPACK fatal error : cannot allocate memory, aborted
xxmr2d: out of memory

@TimRoberts yes, it is a 64 -bit compiler. I understand I  go to the memory limits. Is it any other way how to solve this issue?

@FortranZT Without a real [mcve] no one can know. There can be many kinds of problems. Please show the exact compilation command and the exact error output.

If the error occurs as a result of mpirun, the error is a runtime error and not a compile time error. You can try to execute ulimit -s unlimited before mpirun

You should edit your question and add the commands that you execute and the exact error message.

I am voting to close this question because important information is missing. The commands you are executing and their output is really necessary. It is not just us being annoying.

Hi @VladimirFГероямслава.  The code works perfectly fine for up to L = 17 sites, or  Zglobal(24310,24310). When I increase the system length to L=18 (nst = 48620 ), the  error message is: cannot allocate memory, aborted xxmr2d: out of memory

Use [edit] and show both 1. the exact command you run, 2. the exact error message.

The error message looks very self explanatory.

In a mpi program you want to avoid bringing the distributed matrix onto a single process because, as you see, you can easily run out of memory. So I think really this is an xy problem - you shouldn't be sorting out this error message, you should be calculating the "dynamical properties" with the distributed eigenvectors.

BTW in my own work I usually find PDSYEVD is appreciably quicker than the routine you are using, and rather than the error prone "manual" calculation of the workspace requirements you can ask the routine to calculate what is required for you, see e.g. https://www.smcm.iqfr.csic.es/docs/intel/mkl/mkl_manual/sla/functn_psyev.htm especially the part about setting LWORK = - 1

Indeed, only now I understand that you are doing this global matrix. Avoid these as Ian correctly suggests! Still, I do not understand why allocate(Zglobal...; call pdgemr2d is for all ranks, but deallocate(Zglobal) only for rank 0. There may be some luck with the ILP64 version of MKL because maybe just some counter in the library overflows. I found and old thread where something like that happened.  But it is just a blind try. For that you would have to supply 64-bit integers.

I think @VladimirFГероямслава found the issue: you allocate the zglobal on all MPI processes. Assuming double precision this accounts for 52GB. Increasing the matrix further exceeds the memory. You should allocate only on rank 0 if you really need the matrix on a single rank or keep it distributed as Ian suggested.
